# Cannot open database XXX; requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:

Tags: sql, database, apache-spark-sql, data-warehouse, azure-synapse

While writing the data to an Azure SQL data warehouse using pyspark, we are getting the following error after 30min of execution.

> **Can not open database test; requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId**.

It is running fine for the small dataset that can be completed in less than 30 min or so.

Do have any configuration in the spark that we can pass as part of the connection string or anything

Comment: Can you please show us your pyspark code?

Comment: Hey could you share the complete error message.

Comment: It's hard to investigate, without providing complete error message.

You may go through the Cannot open database "%.*ls" requested by the login. The login failed.

For more information, see Errors 4000 to 4999 [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-2017#errors-4000-to-4999].